# change location of the "lists" and "archives" folders

Tags: apt

apt is using two locations to store downloaded packages and other files:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

These folders can get quite big, even when using `apt-get clean` regularly.

My `/var` is on a separate partition and is relatively small. Is it possible to configure apt, so that is stores its files somewhere ales (i.e. in `/home/apt/`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options.

Change the settings in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
dir::state::lists    /path/to/new/directory;
dir::cache::archives /path/to/new/directory;
```

Mount a larger partitions at the current directories (if you have spare space for a partition):

```
 # mount /dev/sda5 /var/lib/apt
 # mount /dev/sda6 /var/cache/apt
```

Of course, for the above to work, you'll need to create partitions and filesystems first.

Symlink to another location (if you have no space for new partitions, but space within current partitions):

```
# ln -s /home/apt/lib /var/apt/lib
# ln -s /home/apt/cache /var/apt/cache
```

Or as above, but using bind mounts:

```
# mount --bind /home/apt/lib /var/apt/lib
# mount --bind /home/apt/cache /var/apt/cache
```

Answer (score 7):

There are those two condiguration item you need in `apt`:

```
Dir::Cache "/home/user/apt/cache";
Dir::State::Lists "/home/user/apt/lists";
```

Write them into `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99custom`.

Now you have to mkae that folder structure or `apt` will fail:

```
mkdir -p /home/user/apt/cache
mkdir -p /home/user/apt/lists/partial
```

Now, run `apt-get update` to create the needed files in those new directories.